# How to use jq when the response is not a list

Tags: jq

My json response is like this.

```
{
  "level": "info",
  "timestamp": "2022-03-21T16:10:27.060Z",
  "msg": "starting test",
}
{
  "level": "warn",
  "timestamp": "2022-03-21T16:10:27.060Z",
  "msg": "message 2"
}
{
  "level": "error",
  "timestamp": "2022-03-21T16:10:27.060Z",
  "msg": "message 3"
}
```

I want to extract.

Either 3rd message (or nth message) or the message associated with error

How can I do this with jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select` to filter by condition

```sh
jq 'select(.level == "error")'
```

```json
{
  "level": "error",
  "timestamp": "2022-03-21T16:10:27.060Z",
  "msg": "message 3"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/H3u1pHqN4z)

To extract the message, use the `-r` option

```sh
jq -r 'select(.level == "error").msg'
```

```
message 3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Gzbq6QU-cI)

---

If you want to access the nth object, you may want to use a structure whose items you can count. Using the `-s` option would turn the input stream into an array. Using the `--argjson` option enables you using an external (JSON) value for reference:

```sh
jq -sr --argjson n 2 '.[$n].msg'
```

```
message 3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uKiQCUK8jg)

To directly address the nth element of a stream, use the `nth` function, in combination with `inputs` and the `-n` option to address the entire stream at once:

```sh
jq -nr --argjson n 2 'nth($n;inputs).msg'
```

```
message 3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CEgQA7oeIJ)

Comment: Thank you, @pmf. Very helful. I wasn't able to find the use of `-s` in any tutorial or docs immediately.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran The manual is a very good resource. You can find the `-s` option under section [Invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq).